# System email URL is randomly faulty

Tags: emails

A Drupal 6 membership-based site has some rules in place to block registrants based on certain field values (that spammers are using).

When this happens, it triggers the system to send an email to the site admin, as though "Visitors can create accounts but administrator approval is required" is checked, although it's not. While this is a bug, it's not the problem here.

The problem is with the URLs in the email. Sometimes, the link is written correctly, as in:

> `florenefl has applied for an account.`
>   `http://www.sitename.com/user/8872/edit`

and sometimes the `http://` is followed by only 2 "ww"s:

> `fdstyd52as  has applied for an account.`
>   `http://ww.sitename.com/user/8880/edit`

This second link doesn't work for the site admin. It appears to occur randomly. Any ideas why this would happen?

EDIT: the email is sent from user.module line 1720

> case 'register_pending_approval_admin_body': return t("!username has
>   applied for an account.\n\n!edit_uri", $variables, $langcode);

Using the Maillog module, I checked the Welcome emails sent to regular users which also uses `!edit_uri`. I don't see any with the truncated "www".

I also modified the rule to email me when a registrant is blocked, and to include the token for user/*/edit. That URL is also faulty in the emails ... corresponding to when the system emails are faulty. So whenever an account gets blocked, and the email is triggered (whether through the system or through Rules), it appears to randomly truncate the www.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess with a RewriteBase?

Comment: ^ what he says, and are settings in admin/config/system/site-information OK?

Comment: RewriteBase is commented out in htaccess. Under Site Info, the Name is listed as www.sitename.com (with the www) - but that's not used to build the URL in the link anyway, is it?